# What are branching strategy pros and cons for 2 main types

Tags: version-control, team-foundation-server

So at a high level, we have multiple projects/solutions in company and we need to keep them in 1 source control.
Since the number of projects is around 50, we are not creating individual repositories for each of them but instead are all in same repository.
Our branches reflect the environments which is Dev, QCT, STG, PRD.

Having said that, which of the below 2 options should be good for us:

1. Each project has its own folder inside which different branches are created
2. Core repository starts with branches inside which are folders for all project

Any experience based input with these 2 strategies would be greatly appreciated.
Even if its a blog or some other place where this discussion has happened would be nice.

EDIT: Just to be clear, i am not asking whether to create branches or not and to create them for each feature or not. We have already defined we are going to work with 4 branches representing our environments.
The question is the location of those  branches. Should those branches be inside the project for each project or at a global scale.

The one difference for me is inside project branches has more management burden but also allows better control over branch and script control for just that project.

Comment: Are you using TFVC (classic TFS Source Control) or Git for managing the code?
Does your workflow / software architecture mean that developers typically change multiple solutions to deliver features or are they self contained?
Do you have any form of build and deployment automation?
Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To branch or not to branch?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/107884/to-branch-or-not-to-branch)

Comment: @JamesReed We are using TFS for version control. Devs do have to modify multiple solutions some times for single feature delivery. We just have scripts to deploy changes to environments but no automation as such, all manually triggered. We have TFS 2018.

Comment: @gnat i dont see how thats a duplicate. i will edit question for clarification.

Comment: Uh... [see this earlier question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/287329/31234) - don't have branches for your environment.  Although really my bigger concern is that you have so many projects in a single root; normally you'd want to break them up.  Not because you might reuse them (although that's possible), but because it allows you to better manage the connections between them.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I don't know why we should not have branches per environment. We currently need that extensively unless we change our entire business expectations of release process. We pick what changes to release from 1 environment to other and then merge so each merge is not complete branch to branch merge but that of selected change sets.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Also, the 50 or so project are not all interconnected and are mostly isolated systems. Are you suggesting separate repositories?

Comment: @user3754372 - The problem with a "branch per environment" - **especially with what you seem to be describing** -  is that it means that your distributed product _doesn't match_ what your dev/test/qa/etc environment has.  That's a recipe for disaster.  That change you made just in QA - does it work on the dev's workstation?  Did you merge a change from dev directly to prod?  Source control shouldn't be managing your build/test pipeline - it's managing the changes in the final artifact.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse if it goes to higher environment, its only because it was tested in lower environment. Devs only code in dev branch and not in any other branch and if its in QA branch, its already tested  in dev. It also goes to prod via QA then STG and then Prod, not directly.

Comment: `Also, the 50 or so project are not all interconnected and are mostly isolated systems. Are you suggesting separate repositories?` - Uh, if they aren't related, they shouldn't be in the same repositories at all.  For one thing, that's going to pollute the change history ("when did this file get updated?").  _Generally_, you want one repository per executable or deployable library (if you're working in C#, one per NuGet package).  Some repositories bundle multiple executables if they're heavily related - games might bundle the editor with the built game itself, for instance.

Comment: You're still managing your build pipeline via source control.  You should just be handing off whatever artifact got built from the dev branch directly to QAT and later.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse we check history of the file or the project to see changes to a file or project. We are considering the option of multiple repositories but the logic behind what should be separate repository is still in works. But separate per executable or application would be very heavy so we are thinking. Its like 1 prime frontend application is supported by like 15 services dedicated and 5 services shared across multiple projects. So we are considering the repo abstraction but have not settled with logic to define abstraction.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse sorry i am not replying to your comments in order. The reason we cant manage is because like i said, after say 5 changes are released to qa, business may need to(And they already do) release only 3 of the 5 changes in qa to stg and prod. Its wonky expectation may be from typical lifecycle perspective but it is what it is and changing that process is a little farther away for my organization.

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 suggestion

1. Repository

I would prefer to split the projects in multiple repository. All related items in one repository and shared/common projects in one repository. It is easy to maintain in long run, if we have control in individual project level for deployment. In this model, you should have some mechanism to deploy the dependent items in other projects or shared folder.

2. Branching

Instead of following 4 different branches, you can follow a single branch for feature. No need to merge with master. No need to move the code to branches, Dev, QA, UAT and prod deployment happen from same branch